Помогите не могу перевести дату string -> number в Django
Помогите в Django не могу перевести дату string -> number с русского языка
settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
USE_I18N = True


если USE_I18N = False, то все получается, но
index.html
<h5 class="date_verification">{{ device.data_next_colibr }}</h5>
<script src="{% static 'js/now_date.js' %}"></script>


выводит 21 June 2024 г.
вот код на js
now_date.js
let date_verification = document.querySelector('.date_verification');
let date = Date.parse(new Date());
let date_ru = date_verification.innerHTML
let date_ver = Date.parse(date_verification.innerHTML.slice(0, -2));


console.log(date)
console.log(date_ver)

if (date >= date_ver){
    console.log("просрочено");
    document.getElementsByClassName('date_verification')[0].style= "color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold;";
}
else {
    console.log("нормально");
    document.getElementsByClassName('date_verification')[0].style= "color: #279A2B; font-weight: bold;";
}


вот что выводит console.log
1719579296000
now_date.js:8 21 июня 2024 г.
now_date.js:9 NaN
now_date.js:16 нормально


как задать хороший вопрос

Ну как минимум сразу смущает 'ru-RU' вместо 'ru-ru' или даже просто 'ru'

И если вы задаёте дату для парсинга скриптом, то эта дата вообще должна быть записана не на человеческом языке, а в каком-нибудь машиночитаемом формате вроде ISO 8601

Нужно сравнить на ">=" 21 June 2024 г., что показывается на странице, с текущей датой на клиенте?

Да нужно сравнить что показывает на странице с текущей датой

'ru-ru', 'ru'  или 'ru-RU' разницы нет

забираю со странички 21 июня 2024 г. вот ее и не могу перевести в number так как русский не понимает. а если USE_I18N = False то console.log то отображется 21 June 2024 г. и код работает

Поэтому нужно использовать не русский, а машиночитаемый <time datetime="{{ device.data_next_colibr|date:'c' }}">{{ device.data_next_colibr }}</time>

нет не работает все так же

Машиночитаемый не может не работать, значит вы что-то неправильно сделали


Да нужно сравнить что показывает на странице с текущей датой

Предложу такой вариант...
Но удобнее тебе писать вот такой формат ГГГГ-ММ-ДД. Такую строчку можно сразу приводить к формату даты.


const a = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря']
let v = document.querySelector('.date_verification').textContent
v = v.split(' ')
const m = a.indexOf(v[1])
v = new Date(v[2], m, v[0])
const d = new Date()
console.log(d >= v ? 'Просрочено' : 'Нормально')
<p class='date_verification'>21 июня 2024 г.</p>




c 21 июня 2024 г. надо

@user583651, Сделал и для русских месяцев...

Да работает вопрос решен
